# What I should change to get only positive results?

Tags: algorithm, numbers

This is a Delphi code for XOR-Shift algorithm, which is return positive and negative values:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  y : UInt64;
 begin
   y:= 2463534242;
   for i := 1 to 1000 do
    begin
       y := y xor (y shl 13);
       y :=(y shr 17);
       y := y xor (y shl 5);
       ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(y));
    end;
  end;
```

What I should change to get only positive results?

Comment: Isn't `y` unsigned already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UintToStr instead of IntToStr, like:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(UintToStr(y));
```